# create tridion collection class file

Tags: tridion

```cs
using TDS = Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.TDS;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.TDS;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.TDSDefines;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsumerHealth.Web
{
    class Common
    {
        public Common()
        {

        }

        public TridionCollection<Publication> getAllPublicationList() 
        {
            TDSE objTom = new TDSE();
            try
            {
                TridionCollection<Publication> publications = new TridionCollection<Publication>(objTom.GetListPublications(ListColumnFilter.XMLListIDAndTitle));
                return publications;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objTom);
            }

        }
     }
}
```

`public TridionCollection<Publication> getAllPublicationList()`, it shows an error TridionCollection could not found, what am I missing, which dll should I use, 
except this all is working fine.

Answer (score 5):

I think Tridion Collection is user defined class, it is not there in any Tridion dll.

Answer (score 5):

That is not a class that is provided by the Content Manager.

A quick Google search shows that a "[Tridion Generic .NET Collections](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/GenericCollections.aspx)" extension for 2009 provided this. My guess is that you'd have to rewrite it for 2011.

Comment: Manoj code is still using Interop so I guess he is still on 2009.

Comment: Not necessarily. He has had questions for 2011 before, so it could just be code migration.

Answer (score 0):

You need [this](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/GenericCollections.aspx) assembly provided by your dear friends at SDLTridionWorld.com.

This was written for Tridion 2009 (as was already mentioned before) and as far as I know it might not work on Tridion 2011. Given that it is [open source](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/reciprocal_public_license.aspx), feel free to change it and adapt it as needed, and report it back to SDL Tridion World so they can update it with a newer version.

Comment: Indeed - it's open source, but not free (as in freedom)

Comment: If you improve it, you are _obliged_ to contribute your fixes.